# Python - No module named foo

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I am trying to write a simple program for an led cube. First I need to execute one of the other sample programs provided, but I'm getting the error "No module named cube_interface" when I try and run a python program.

Now before you mark this question as duplicate, and refer me to the 7,776 similar questions stack overflow, let me tell disclose that I've already tried implementing the solutions provided on 14 other SO questions, and followed 3 blogs covering how to fix this error, with no luck.

OS: Mac OsX 10.8.1
Python: 2.7.5
Repo: https://github.com/chadharrington/all_spark_cube

The example program is src/tetris.py

The module is src/all_spark_cube_client

```
   ├── Makefile
    └── src
        ├── LICENSE.txt
        ├── all_spark_cube_client
        │   ├── __init__.py
        │   └── __init__.pyc
        ├── all_spark_cube_client.egg-info
        │   ├── PKG-INFO
        │   ├── SOURCES.txt
        │   ├── dependency_links.txt
        │   ├── not-zip-safe
        │   ├── requires.txt
        │   └── top_level.txt
        ├── build
        │   ├── bdist.macosx-10.9-intel
        │   └── lib
        │       └── all_spark_cube_client
        │           └── __init__.py
        ├── client_demo.py
        ├── colors.py
        ├── dist
        │   └── all_spark_cube_client-0.1-py2.7.egg
        ├── load_test.py
        ├── setup.py
        ├── supervisord.conf
        ├── supervisord_init_script.debian
        ├── supervisord_init_script.redhat
        └── tetris.py
```

When I try and run the tetris.py program, I get an error "No module named.."

```
python tetris.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tetris.py", line 5, in <module>
    from all_spark_cube_client import CubeClient
  File "/Users/sowen/Code/all_spark_cube/software/clients/python_client/src/all_spark_cube_client/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from cube_interface import CubeInterface
ImportError: No module named cube_interface
```

Many of the answers suggest adding pwd . /Library/Python ect.. to the PYTHONPATH. I've tried implementing all of them independently, and even combined all suggestions into one frakenstein path as shown, with no luck.

```
cd ~/Code/all_spark_cube/software/clients/python_client
export PYTHONPATH=$PATH:$PYTHONPATH:`pwd`:`pwd`/src:.:/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
```

I've tried building the python module

```
$sudo python setup.py build
 running build
 running build_py
 file all_spark_cube_client.py (for module all_spark_cube_client) not found
 file all_spark_cube_client.py (for module all_spark_cube_client) not found
```

I've tried installing the python module (It doesn't give any errors, but I still am unable to run tetris.py)

```
 cd ~/Code/all_spark_cube/software/clients/python_client/src/
 sudo python setup.py install
```

How can I execute the tetris.py program?

Additional Resources

http://docs.python.org/2/using/mac.html
http://www.confusedcoders.com/random/python-module-importerror-no-module-named-pocketsphinx

Comment: Your list of files doesn't include anything called `cube_interface`.  Where is `cube_interface`?

Comment: Did you follow the list of instructions on the web page? Install the prereqs, clone the repo, make, etc.?

Comment: The instructions are for the server, I'm trying to build the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to build `cube_interface`:

See: https://github.com/chadharrington/all_spark_cube/tree/master/software/thrift

You need to build this with the `gen_py` tool.

i.e: (*I assume*:):

```
cd /path/to/all_spark_cube/software/thrift/
make
cp cube_interface.py /path/to/python/site-packages
```

Comment: Thanks!, the `make` didn't work, but I think I'm on the right track `make: thrift: No such file or directory
make: *** [gen-py] Error 1
`

Comment: You _have_ to install **thrift** obviously. Please follow their instructions *carefully* :)

Comment: I need the client. Their instructions are for the server,

Comment: You will likely need both regardless of whether or not you're planning on running up the server. I'm not 100% sure -- but often server/client libraries go hand-in-hand.